# Is required to name variables in certain way so can access their values via jstl?

Tags: java, jstl, javabeans

When accessing java beans from .jsp using jstl is the java bean required to follow a particular naming convention. This is to enable the jsp page (using jstl) page to access the values in the java bean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class should follow the [JavaBean conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans#JavaBean_conventions).